# Sort by analysis fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Consider indexes

- Foo {id, bazs_count}
- Bar {id, foo_id}
- Baz {bar_id}
- Foo (1) - (0..*) Bar (1) - (0..*) Baz

I need a way to sort foos by their bazs count (count of bazs linked to bars that linked to foo). Baz index grows with time so bazs count dynamically changes. The way I found is to make some analytics app that continiously updates bazs_count in Foo items. Is there a better way?

**Clarification about how data is formed:** I index bars with their bazs. After that I process all bazs and link each to some bar. So I don't know the foo_id for bar and baz when I index them.

Answer (score 0):

Update the field bazs_count of the index Foo with a batch process OR consolidate your index Foo with all the data Foo+Bar+Baz with the nested document feature of Elasticsearch and use the agregate API to sort your Foos items by a simple count.

Comment: I think the batch won't work because I don't know foo_id for baz when I index them. Only DB knows. Nested document option has the same problem. Added some clarifications to the first post about how data is added.